# How to pad a 2d array with variable length per row on the left and right to form a bigger 2d array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d array like

```
small = np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3))

array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

I want to apply a padding, each row to pad variable 0s on the left. And to make sure the result 2d array is of shape 3 x 8. (padding 0s on the right)

```
offset = np.array([1, 3, 2])
```

So that the result looks like

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

What's the best way to achieve that?

thanks to @Divakar solution. I ran some benchmarks on the following methods.

```
def f1(small, offset, ncols):
    nrows, num_small_cols = small.shape
    big = np.zeros((nrows, ncols))
    inner = np.empty_like(small, dtype=np.int64)
    for i in range(num_small_cols):
        inner[:, i] = offset + i
    big[np.arange(nrows)[:, None], inner] = small
    return big

def f2(small, offset, ncols):
    n = small.shape[1]
    r = np.arange(ncols)
    offset2 = offset[:,None]
    # This took a lot of time
    mask = (offset2 <= r) & (offset2 + n > r)
    out = np.zeros_like(mask, dtype=np.float64)
    out[mask] = small.ravel()
    return out

def f3(small, offset, ncols):
    n = small.shape[1]
    m = ncols - n
    small_pad = np.zeros((len(small), n + 2*m))
    small_pad[:,m:m+n] = small    
    w = view_as_windows(small_pad, (1,ncols))[:,:,0]
    return w[np.arange(len(offset)), ncols-offset-n]

n = 10000
offset = np.repeat(np.array([1, 3, 2]), n)
small = np.random.rand(n * 3, 5)

%timeit f1(small, offset, 9)
# 1.32 ms

%timeit f2(small, offset, 9)
# 2.24 ms

%timeit f3(small, offset, 9)
# 1.3 ms
```

Comment: As it turns out using an array for indexing is faster for the `strided` one. Edited my post with it. So, could you please re-run those tests?

Comment: @Divakar Oh, I didn't know `np.arange` is so much better than `range` in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach #1**

We can use [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to create a mask for assigning into those positions and then assign into a zeros-intialized array -

```
def pad_offsetpos(small, ncols):
    n = small.shape[1]
    r = np.arange(ncols)
    mask = (offset[:,None] <= r) & (offset[:,None]+n > r)
    out = np.zeros(mask.shape)
    out[mask] = small.ravel()
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [327]: small
Out[327]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

In [328]: offset
Out[328]: array([1, 3, 2])

In [329]: pad_offsetpos(small, ncols=8)
Out[329]: 
array([[0., 0., 1., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 3., 4., 5., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 6., 7., 8., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

**Approach #2**

We can also leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) for efficient patch extraction after padding the input array with enough zeros on either sides -

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

def pad_offsetpos_strided(small, ncols):
    n = small.shape[1]
    m = ncols - n
    small_pad = np.zeros((len(small), n + 2*m))
    small_pad[:,m:m+n] = small    
    w = view_as_windows(small_pad, (1,ncols))[:,:,0]
    return w[np.arange(len(offset)), ncols-offset-n]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PaddedMat=numpy.zeros(shape=[3,8],dtype="float")
```

and then loop to fill it.

```
PaddedMat[i,offset[i]:offset[i]+3]=small[i,:]
```

etc...